# how replace string repeated pattern at his start ,linux terminal?

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, csh

I want to edit a string that I get using regular expression in linux shell but I failed.

the thing I want to do is at the start of the string to change repeatedlly occurrence of "00" to "1"

let say : `00000120001 to 110100001` but I failed to that.

I tried:

```
echo 00000120001 | sed 's/^\`\<00/1/g'
```

but got 1000120001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can do it with a single regex; I have a solution with juggling with the hold and pattern spaces of `sed`.

In one line:

```
sed 'h;s/[^0].*//;s/00/1/g;x;s/^0*//;x;G;s/\n//' <<< '00000120001'
```

With details:

```
sed 'h          # copy input line to hold space
     s/[^0].*// # keep only 00..0 prefix in pattern space
     s/00/1/g   # replace double 0s by 1s in pattern space
     x          # swap hold and pattern spaces (hold is now 110, pattern 00000120001
     s/^0*//    # remove 00..0 prefix from pattern space
     x          # swap hold and pattern spaces (hold is now 120001, pattern 110
     G          # append hold space to pattern space (pattern is 110\n120001)
     s/\n//'    # remove \n from pattern
<<< '00000120001'
```

Comment: it's work great but I had to change it to:

echo 00000120001 | sed 'h;s/1.*//;s/00/1/g;x;s/^0*//;x;G;s/\n//'

Comment: The `<<<` syntax works for bash shell. When using it I forgot you add a `csh` tag on your question. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

with a Perl command line:

```
echo 00000120001 | perl -pe 's/(?|^(.)|\G(?<=(.))\1)\1/1/g'
```

For zero only:

```
echo 00000120001 | perl -pe 's/\G00/1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk` you can do:

```
echo '00000120001' | awk '$0==""{printf "1"} $0 && !index($0, "\n")
          {p=1; printf $0 RS; next} $0{printf $0}' RS='00'
110120001
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s/^(1*)00/\11/;ta' file
```

Replace zero or more `1`'s followed by `00` by those `1`'s and another `1`, repeat until failure.